# .LESS together with Razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, sass, less

Is it possible to use Razor View Engine (ASP.NET MVC) together with .LESS (similar to SASS - http://lesscss.org/ for .NET), since they're both using "@blah"?

What I want to achieve is to create .LESS css files, mixed with Razor.

**UPDATED:**

Sorry for being a bit unspecific. What I want to do is to use Razor View Engine WITHIN the .less (dotlesscss) css files. This would be nice in order to e.g. pass site-settings like Theme customized from an admin into the css file.

Problem is that the syntax will crash.

An alternative is to use C# or some other View Engine instead.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to do? Do you want to use Razor to generate a .less file that will then be used to generate a .css file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should consider using Justin Etheredge's SquishIt library. Not only does it include the dotlesscss library, it will combine and minify your CSS and Javascript with ease!

- [Blog post regarding SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/05/26/SquishIt-The-Friendly-ASPNET-JavaScript-and-CSS-Squisher.aspx)
- [Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt)

### Here's an example of how I use SquishIt in Razor.

The following code will combine, minify and LESSify all the CSS files referenced into one CSS file. It will do the same with the Javascript files.

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(
  SquishIt.Framework.Bundle.Css()
    .Add("~/media/css/reset.css")
    .Add("~/media/css/style.less")
    .Add("~/media/css/handheld.css")
    .Render("~/media/css/combined_#.css"))

@MvcHtmlString.Create(
  SquishIt.Framework.Bundle.JavaScript()
    .Add("~/media/js/geo.js")
    .Add("~/media/js/jquery-1.4.4.js")
    .Add("~/media/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
    .Add("~/media/js/jquery.validate.js")
    .Add("~/media/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
    .Render("~/media/js/combined_#.js"))
```

*Output looks like this:*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/combined_312454.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" href="/media/js/combined_312454.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE (Over 1 year later)...**
Another project you might want to look at is [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) which pretty much does everything SquishIt does (and more).

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: There is also Chirpy if you would like it to be compiled in your IDE http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ but then you run into the problem that all the computers you work from need the plugin installed in VS...

Comment: You say dotlesscss is included with squishit? I can't seem to get that working... and can't really find anything on the internet about it.. more info?

Comment: @Ryan Did you try clicking on the two links in my answer to find info about it?

Comment: Yes, and also I figured out I needed the .less extention on my file lol :P

Comment: Is it possible to control the versions of the output files, for example if i manually changed one line of css and want client browser to load that new version(without changing web.config and restarting application)?

Comment: @bigb I have run into this issue as well. SquishIt is opinionated in this regard. I don't know of a good workaround for this. It is sort of annoying.

Comment: Could you provide any assistance as to why you need to wrap the `SquishIt` call in `@MvcHtmlString`? Without it, the `link` tag appears inside quotes, but I'm having trouble finding resources on why.

Comment: How is that answer accepted? Bundling is not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 3):

LESS and the Razor engine are not related.

If you are interested in using LESS, check out dotlesscss. See its [Git repository](http://github.com/dotless/dotless) and [wiki](http://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki). For some reason, its [main website is down](http://www.tigraine.at/2010/08/17/www-dotlesscss-com-is-down/) since august and they haven't brought it back up.

Comment: Yea I was referring to dotlesscss.. Figured the site was down. Sucks. GitHub to the rescue! ;)

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.5 and MVC 4 now has this out of the box

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification