# How can I apply less stylesheets as a css on the fly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, less, dotless

Recently I started to experiment with LESS, and Im really enthusiastic about it. Its a really nice tool to optimize css. Anyway I installed into my project file as it was written on their website 4 steps, very EZ. 
I use MVC3 framework with razor engine, and in my view I just can not apply the .less files as a css for the browser.

When I used like this, its just worked brilliantly

```
 <style type="text/css">
       @Less.Parse(".transparency(@opacity: 50) {opacity:@opacity/100; filter:~'alpha(opacity = '@opacity~')';}.disabled {.transparency}")
 </style>
```

But when I tried to apply it as a css file the browser just ignored it

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/Content/Css/Pm/Pm.less" media="screen" />
```

I had no compiling error in my less file, and the compiled less just looked great, I thought dotless going to handle it automatically, but apparently thats not the case.
Im not sure what would be the best approach, read out the less file content as a stream and write it back into a css file or modify the view engine like int this [article](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2010/07/02/dynamic-dot-less-css-with-asp-net-mvc-2/) or write a helper [like this](http://samritchie.net/2011/05/23/dotlessresult-mvc-actionresult-for-dotless/)?

Comment: This might answer your question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081084/less-together-with-razor

Comment: I dont want to use squish it. That uses too much cpu power, any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you detail what kind of environment you are using?
Are you running on the asp.net dev server? In any case please post the relevant httpHandelers section from your web.config.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about CPU usage, you could always look at using precompilation, take a look at this question: [Visual studio - precompile - dotless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176675/visual-studio-precompile-dotless/9155776#9155776)

The answers give a number of options:

- [Pre-build task in your project file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2181543/973292)
- [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/)
- Command-line using the dotless compiler
- A number of people also wrote custom build tools (including myself): [JsBuildTools](https://github.com/paultyng/JsBuildTools), [LessCssForVisualStudio](https://github.com/StevePotter/LessCssForVisualStudio)