# Is there a way to write an embedded LESS code within a Razor View?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, less

I am doing the web project with ASP.NET MVC 5 and it would be nice to use LESS instead of CSS just inside of .cshtml (Views) files.

I have founded several solutions, but all of them force me to use individual .less files.

It perfectly works if I embed my css in the  section within any View file(.cshtml).

Is it possible to use LESS instead of CSS inside this section?

Comment: Does this answer help you at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081084/less-together-with-razor

Comment: @NathanielFlick wow, it's amazing, I have to try this out! My problem is in I didn't find this method in time. I took the dirty (maybe not :) ) method. Every Action is two files: actionName.cshtml and styles.less. A couple of these files are in its own folder. Content/styles.less imports all of these "namespaced" .lessES and Gulp generates the general styles.css file.